# Bigtable Google Happybase Python KeyError when trying to do `counter_inc`

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable, happybase

I'm not sure why but `counter_inc` method is not working, no emulator, pointing to a development real instance.

Snippet:

```
from google.cloud import bigtable
from google.cloud import happybase

client = bigtable.Client(project='robbie-ai', admin=True)
instance = client.instance('visio-bt-staging')
connection = happybase.Connection(instance=instance)
connection.create_table('commons_TestBTModelsTable', {'family': None, 'counters': None})
table = connection.table('commons_TestBTModelsTable')
table.put('row-key1', {'family:surname': 'Trump'})
print("Getting row 'row-key1': {}".format(table.row(b'row-key1')))
table.counter_inc(b'row1', b'counters:qual1')
```

If I do `table.counter_inc(b'row1', 'counters:qual1')` is exactly the same.

When executed as script:

```
root@2d21638ea17f:/app# python scripts/counters.py
Getting row 'row-key1': {b'family:surname': b'Trump'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/counters.py", line 28, in <module>
    table.counter_inc(b'row1', b'counters:qual1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/happybase/table.py", line 591, in counter_inc
    column_cells = modified_cells[column_family_id][column_qualifier]
KeyError: 'qual1'
```

Is it a bug or this snippet has a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitively a bug, they have different types for the column id qualifier and the returned dict key type, the one that it is returned by `commit()`, while the one you got from split was decoded into str,

here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python-happybase/blob/master/src/google/cloud/happybase/table.py#L577

here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python-happybase/blob/master/src/google/cloud/happybase/table.py#L582

and here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python-happybase/blob/master/src/google/cloud/happybase/table.py#L591

if you go lower level:

```
# As it is in the source code
row = table._low_level_table.row(b'row-key1', append=True)
column_family_id, column_qualifier = 'qual1'.split(':')
row.increment_cell_value(column_family_id, column_qualifier, 1)
row.commit()
"""outputs
{'counters': {b'qual1': [(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01',
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 12, 14, 2, 28, 858000, tzinfo=<UTC>))]}}
"""
# of course if using the original portion code it breaks with KeyError as the returned key type is bytes
# Get the cells in the modified column,
column_cells = modified_cells[column_family_id][column_qualifier]
"""outputs
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-fe55fb8c47c5> in <module>()
      1 # Get the cells in the modified column,
----> 2 column_cells = modified_cells[column_family_id][column_qualifier]

KeyError: 'counters'
"""
# But it works if re-encoded the column 
# Get the cells in the modified column,
column_cells = modified_cells[column_family_id][column_qualifier.encode()]
column_cells
[(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04',
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 12, 14, 16, 18, 150000, tzinfo=<UTC>))]
```

This is for Python 3.5.2, anyway is strange that the `commit` response is returning heterogeneous key types, what seems wrong to me.

**Workaround until they fix it in pypi:** Override the `counter_inc` method with the above encoding